# EASY - How can I add text into all text files in a certain directory using script?

Tags: text, for-loop, addition

I need to write a script that adds a certain text into all the text files in a certain directory. Here's what I have:

$1

for f in *.txt

do

echo "$2" >> *.txt     <-- **HERE's** the problem and I don't understand why

done

...everything else works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are missing a semicolon. Second, you have to use the variable you defined to iterate through all the text-files:

```
for f in *.txt; do
  echo "$1" >> $f
done
```

I don't know for which reason you used $2. If you really need more than one argument for your script, you have to adjust the script accordingly.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you very much sir!

oh and the $1 stands for the path to the directory, $2 stands for the text I want to enter to the text files :)